# mdb-tools mySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mdbtools

I have a .mdb file I'm trying to export into a mySQL database.
Using `mdb-schema Data.mdb | mysql -u root -p Database`
I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Attachments]
 (
    [ItemID]            Long Integer, 
    [Description]           Text (510), 
    [Pare' at line 1
```

The code output of mdb-schema (before piping actually looks like that) <>

```
  1 -- ----------------------------------------------------------
  2 -- MDB Tools - A library for reading MS Access database files
  3 -- Copyright (C) 2000-2011 Brian Bruns and others.
  4 -- Files in libmdb are licensed under LGPL and the utilities under
  5 -- the GPL, see COPYING.LIB and COPYING files respectively.
  6 -- Check out http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net
  7 -- ----------------------------------------------------------
  8 
  9 -- That file uses encoding UTF-8
 10 
 11 CREATE TABLE [Attachments]
 12  (
 13         [ItemID]                        Long Integer,
 14         [Description]                   Text (510),
 15         [ParentItemID]                  Long Integer,
 16         [Path]                  Memo/Hyperlink (255),
 17         [AttachmentType]                        Long Integer,
 18         [Notes]                 Text (510),
 19         [Imported]                      Boolean NOT NULL
 20 );
 21
```

+ some other tables

Which effectively means the syntax error is in the first line after comments? Can you help me out with this? To by lame eyes it look valid.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does MySQL recognize square brackets as delimiters for table/column names? I seem to recall that MySQL used backquotes (`) for that purpose. I also wonder how MySQL would react to 'Memo/Hyperlink' as a column type. (However, I haven't done much work with MySQL for a while.)

Comment: I believe you need `varchar`, not `Text`.

Comment: Changing [(.+)] to '$1' didn't change anything. Still error on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man mdb-schema`, we can include an optional `backend` parameter after the database name. When I tried

```
mdb-schema test.mdb mysql > output.txt
```

The output file contained this

```sql
-- ----------------------------------------------------------
-- MDB Tools - A library for reading MS Access database files
-- Copyright (C) 2000-2011 Brian Bruns and others.
-- Files in libmdb are licensed under LGPL and the utilities under
-- the GPL, see COPYING.LIB and COPYING files respectively.
-- Check out http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net
-- ----------------------------------------------------------

-- That file uses encoding UTF-8

CREATE TABLE `Contacts`
 (
    `ID`            int, 
    `LastName`          varchar (510), 
    `FirstName`         varchar (510), 
    `Notes`         text (255)
);
```

It certainly looks a lot closer to MySQL syntax than the sample in the question.